# How to open examples - SS3?

Tags: subsonic3

Trying to open th solution on VS2k8 PRO and says:

The project file - ...path\ActiveRecord.csproj cannot be opened

### The project type is not supported by this installation

The project file - ...path\SimpleRepo.csproj cannot be opened

The project type is not supported by this installation

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have c# and/or web application projects installed as part of visual studio. Can you create c#/web application projects?

EDIT: You also need VS sp1 and asp.net mvc installed to open the examples

Comment: Yes I created a web application on C# and putted a Response.Write on Page_Load and it says OK!
Can you help me trying to open SS3 examples?

Comment: You'll also need VS sp1 and asp.net mvc installed

Comment: SS must be used only on MVC projects? Can not it be used on WebForms?
Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded MVC and VS now opens the sln example.
Mr Adam, can you help me on a simple example on how to open a connection to a DB and do a basic operations on it (CRUD) using WebForms? Where can I find it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you watched the 5 minute demo? http://subsonicproject.com/docs/The_5_Minute_Demo